# Calculating contour integral two ways with different results

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to resolve an apparent contradiction and have yet to find my mistake. The goal is to calculate

$$
I = \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{1/(w-1)^2}{w-z} dw
$$

where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is fixed and $\Gamma_R$ is a circle of radius $R$ centered at $1$. Take $R$ to be arbitrarily large. Then the integral is the sum of the poles of the integrand, which is just the pole at $z$ since the pole at $1$ is second order with zero residue. From this approach I find

$$
I = \frac{2\pi i}{(z-1)^2}
$$

On the other hand, it's immediately clear that the integrand goes as $R^{-3}$ while the length of the contour goes as $R$, so that as $R\rightarrow\infty$, $I\rightarrow 0$. From this approach

$$
I = 0
$$

Obviously I have overlooked something. Can anyone help me track down my error?

Comment: this doesn't resolve everything, but if $z=1$, then you don't have a pole at $1$, since you just have a zero of order $3$ at $1$. but, of course, you can tell me that $z=1.00001$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen it is inside. how is the question at all vague? you fix $z$ and then take $R$ very large (larger than $2|z|$, say).

Comment: @math Why does the pole at $1$ have zero residue?; I get the residue to be minus the residue at $z$ (assuming $z \ne 1$)

Comment: @Conrad don't second order poles have 0 residue?

Comment: @math - the Laurent series may have a term of order $1$ (does here using the formula for residues)

Comment: @Conrad can you be more precise please? is your answer to my question "second order poles do have $0$ residue, but there is not a second order pole at $1$ in this question"? also, what Laurent series are you talking about?

Comment: @math $\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z}$ has a pole of order $2$ but also non zero residue

Comment: @Conrad ok, it seems me and bgreen were viewing $\frac{1}{(w-1)^2(w-z)}$ the same as $\frac{1-z}{(w-1)^2}$ pole-wise, but I guess that is not the case, by looking at the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(w-1)^2(w-z)}$ (why didn't you answer my question)?

Comment: @math - wasn't sure what you asked, sorry

Comment: @Conrad you said "the laurent series may have a term of order $1$" and then "[it] does here". I asked "what Laurent series are you talking about". May I ask how you are unsure?

Comment: @math again I apologize if  I was unclear but I thought we use the same notions - I will put an answer below which shows how I thought of this problem when i saw it

Comment: @Conrad dude, I'm just asking you which function were you referring to when you said "the Laurent series here has a term of order $1$"? how is this confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue formula at a pole of order $2$ for some analytic $f$ at some point $y$ is $lim_{w \to y}((w-y)^2f(w))'$

So here $f(w)=\frac{1/(w-1)^2}{w-z}, y=1$ and we assume for simplicity $z \ne 1$

Then $g(w)=(w-1)^2f(w)=\frac{1}{w-z}$, so $g'(1)=-\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ hence there is a residue at $1$ and it cancels the residue at $z$, so no contradiction as the integral is indeed $0$

Comment: Thank you! I had initially tried to do this by a power series expansion of $\frac{1}{w-z}$ about $w=1$ but had found no -1st term in $\frac{1/(w-1)^2}{w-z}$. I returned to those calculations and found I had misread/mentally reversed the numerator and denominator in the expansion - fixing that, I find the same result as you. It's always the simple mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

HINT;

Using partial fraction expansion, we have

$$ \frac1{(w-z)(w-1)^2} =\frac{1/(z-1)^2}{w-z}-\frac{1/(z-1)^2}{w-1}+\frac{1/(z-1)}{(w-1)^2}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thank you! I had initially tried to do this by a power series expansion of $\frac{1}{w-z}$ about $w=1$ but had found no -1st term in $\frac{1/(w-1)^2}{w-z}$. I returned to those calculations and found I had misread/mentally reversed the numerator and denominator in the expansion - fixing that, I find the same result as you. It's always the simple mistakes...